# Displaying a line-chart along with some text fields inside a popUpTemplate.

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I am building a sample web-mapping application using the ESRI 4.5 API. I have a single marker with a popUp on it. When an user clicks on the pop-up I want some text fields along with a line chart inside the popUp template. Right now, I am able to do both individually but I am not finding a way to display both of them together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<style>
    html,
    body,
    #mapDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

</style>

<script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/PopupTemplate",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "dojox/charting/Chart2D",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, SceneView, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, Chart2D) {

        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "streets",
            ground: "world-elevation"
        });

        var view = new SceneView({
            container: "mapDiv",
            map: map,
            scale: 50000000,
            center: [77.580643, 12.972442]
        });


        var point = {
            type: "point",
            longitude: 77.580643,
            latitude: 12.972442
        };


        var markerSymbol = {
            type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
            color: [226, 119, 40],
            outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                color: [255, 255, 255],
                width: 2
            }
        };




        tagValues = [8, 12, 23, 543, 1, 324, 10]

        var c = dojo.create("div", {
            id: "demoChart"
        }, dojo.create('div'));

        var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D(c);
        chart.addPlot("default");
        chart.addSeries("Series A", tagValues);
        chart.addAxis("y", {
            vertical: true,
            fixLower: "major",
            fixUpper: "major",
            title: "Temperature",
            min: 0
        })
        chart.addAxis("x", {
            fixLower: "major",
            fixUpper: "major"

        });


         var lineAtt = {
            Name: "Keystone Pipeline",
            Owner: "TransCanada",
            Length: "3,456 km"
        };


        // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: point,
            symbol: markerSymbol,
            attributes: lineAtt,
            popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{Name}",
                //How do I change the line below to display the chart along with some text fields.
                content: c
            }
        });

        view.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
        chart.render();

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with require module/function argument agreement. It should look like this:

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "dojox/charting/Chart2D",
    "esri/PopupTemplate",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, SceneView, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, Chart2D) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use description tag in the popupTemplate. I have given a sample code below.

```
var template = new PopupTemplate({
          title: "your title",
          description: "your description",
          content: c
)};
```

Hope this works.